# Allow access to a directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, permissions

I've can easely find a lot of .httaccess blocking examples, but in my case I would actually do the quit opposite, and allow access from all in subfolders matching `(^|/)/thumbs/(/|$)`

> If you have a directory named 'blah' that you want to block, but it
>   can occur anywhere in your directory tree, use the following: 
>   RewriteEngine On RewriteRule (^|/)blah(/|$) - [F]

Any body who know how to accomplish this?

Comment: Short answer: create an empty htaccess file in the folder.

Comment: starkeen that would lead to a lot of manual work as they are generated by the web script

Answer (score 5):

Well if you to want to allow `/thumbs/` directories, it depends how they are being blocked in the first place. If they're blocked with normal Apache access permissions, then something like this will do it, but must go in the main server config at root level or in a `<VirtualHost>` and not in a `.htaccess` file.

```
<DirectoryMatch "/thumbs/">
    Require all granted
</DirectoryMatch>
```

Or for Apache before 2.4:

```
<DirectoryMatch "/thumbs/">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</DirectoryMatch>
```

Allowing is quite different from blocking with a forbidden response that you cited. You have to ask why is it not already allowed if it's within the web document root? Then open up that block.